# iOS 8.3 problems with location

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm developing an application that uses the user's location. Im using core location.
But in certain screens it does not catch location. The steps are exactly these:

**MainViewController:**
In `MainViewController` I request the authorization. It's worked. I allow the authorization to location.

```
if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
     if locationManager.respondsToSelector("requestWhenInUseAuthorization") == true {
          locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
     }
}
```

**ViewController 1:**
I touch in option 1, segue to `ViewController` 1, here i start updating location. It's worked. A catch correct the location.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
   locationManager.delegate = self
   locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    NSLog("Location has stopped updating")
}
```

**ViewController 2:**
Now I back to `MainViewController`, and touch to option 2, the view segue to `ViewController` 2. But here in action button `touchHowToGo`, dont start updating location, the method has called, but not worked. If i return to `ViewController` 1 location start normal. Only in this screen not work.

```
IBAction func touchHowToGo(sender: AnyObject) {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

- In this three View Controllers I'm importing `CoreLocation`;
- In `ViewController` 1 and `ViewController` 2 setted `CLLocationManagerDelegate`;
- In `.plist` I added the key;
- In tha app panel settings already on to location WhenInUse;
- The app not crash and not `didFailError` only never update location

**Catch location:**
In all `ViewControllers` i used method delegate:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
    NSLog("Location has updated with success %f - %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude)
}
```

I have tried `didUpdateLocations`, but without success

Comment: where you are catching the location ? can you show us the code ?

Comment: @hardik.shah added the code, basically I catch on delegate method

Comment: can you disable this line for a while sharedInstance.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation() and check its working on VC2  ?

Comment: @hardik.shah yes, im sorry, i have trying many alternatives, but all without succes, i forggot change this segment code

Comment: so is it working now ?

Comment: No =/, i have tried to apply location manager in singleton, and local controller. but not worked, only in ViewController 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86731/discussion-between-hardik-shah-and-gian).